# Can't use 'vagrant' after installling 'jekyll' with error: 'can't find gem vagrant'

Tags: vagrant, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

After the install of [jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) with `gem install jekyll`, my [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant) commands fails with:

```
$ vagrant up
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem vagrant (>= 0.a) with executable vagrant (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:25:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem vagrant (>= 0.a) with executable vagrant (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:25:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem vagrant (>= 0.a) with executable vagrant (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:25:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem vagrant (>= 0.a) with executable vagrant (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:25:in `<main>'
```

```
$ LANG=C dpkg -l vagrant
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version              Architecture Description
+++-==============-====================-============-==========================================================>
ii  vagrant        2.2.19+dfsg-1ubuntu1 all      Tool for building and distributing virtualized development>
```

What I need as a temporary workaround (the variables are declared in `~/.bashrc`):

```
$ unset GEM_HOME GEM_PATH
```

Now, I'm able to run `vagrant`. What is a definitive solution to avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the declaration of

```
export GEM_PATH=$HOME/gems # to remove
```

This is sufficient:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/gems"
export PATH=PATH=~/gems/bin:$PATH
```